# Android - How to close or hide a view and bring it back

Tags: android, view, visibility

I have three views in my app and I would like to be able to hide them and bring them back selectively. I have tried using the following triggered by a button click event:

```
 if(SurfaceView().isShown()==true){
            SurfaceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else if(!SurfaceView().isShown()){
            SurfaceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

However this usually freezes up the views and then closes the app with no errors except the following :

NvRmChannelSubmitt: NvError_IoctlFailed with error code 14

EDIT: the view that Im referring to is actually the _glsurfaceview in the renderactivity from min3d

```
public class RendererActivity extends Activity implements ISceneController
{
public Scene scene;
protected static GLSurfaceView _glSurfaceView;
```

My main activity extend RenderActivity

EDIT: added logcat dump

The only things showing up upon the closing are these

```
03-02 15:57:00.338: I/Min3D(28364): Renderer.onSurfaceChanged()
03-02 15:57:00.355: D/(28364): NvRmChannelSubmit: NvError_IoctlFailed with error code 14
```

Comment: Show the initialization of your variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you might have a copy/paste typo in your code. Are you trying to show the `glSurfaceView` if the `SurfaceView` is invisible? If so, try this:

```
if( SurfaceView().isShown() )
{
  glSurfaceView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else if ( !SurfaceView().isShown() )
{
  glSurfaceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i noticed that after I had posted it already lol. I fixed it up above and put the error it gave me.

Comment: Is there a LogCat stack trace you can copy/paste?

Comment: I pasted the spot in the logcat where everything closes.There are nothing else in the logcat at that point related to my app everything else is system chatter related to verizon bs ware

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

So I fixed my problem. I think when your using opengl and glsurfaceviews you have to change what I have above to the following:

```
   if(glSurfaceView().isShown()==true){
            SurfaceView().onPause();<----------------------added to pause view
            SurfaceView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if(!glSurfaceView().isShown()){
            SurfaceView().onResume();<---------------------added to resume view
            SurfaceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

The SurfaceView().onPause() tells the glsurfaceview that I want the renderer to pause and vice versa for onResume().

Now Im not sure this is the end all fix for this situation but it is working for like this.

Answer (score 1):

Using View.GONE will make the view invisible, and will not take up any space in your layout.

Comment: I did try using that and it gave me the same result where all the views disappeared and finally the app closed out. Also these views are not within a xml layout but added dynamically using just java. All three views take up the whole screen and are layered. The backgrounds are transparent and objects are moving in each view.